# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender not creating new file every day

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, windows-server-2016

I have a number of web applications which run on separate Tomcat 9 instances on Windows Server 2016.

Each app is configured to use log4j 1.2.17 and each creates a new log file each day.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="roller" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="d:/logs/appname/appname.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[slf5s.start]%d{DATE}[slf5s.DATE]%n%p[slf5s.PRIORITY]%n%x[slf5s.NDC]%n%t[slf5s.THREAD]%n%c[slf5s.CATEGORY]%n%l[slf5s.LOCATION]%n%m[slf5s.MESSAGE]%n%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    ...
</log4j>
```

From time to time one app does not roll-over and keeps writing to the base log file. I have not been able to spot any differences in the log file but this time I noticed that the log didn't change since I dropped in an updated WAR.

Could this be the problem? I dropped the updated WAR in to the `webapps` folder and Tomcat automatically installed it on-the-fly. I have now stopped and restarted the service and will observe what happens over the next days.

Comment: I am not sure what the single quotes around the dot means in your DatePattern. I use "<param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>" which works perfectly fine.

Comment: Log4j and Tomcat: You have to be aware of some classloading issues. Is the log4j.jar part of each's webapplication lib, or does it reside in the tomcats lib folder (the same applies to the configuration file)? If you want to have separate loggin for each application you must provide the jar and xml within the webapp's classpath and configure Tomcat's classloading "childfirst".